# Does Android compile "recognize" identical PNGs

Tags: android

If I use 4 images in my App, all in the drawable folder, and they are the same image, does Android compile recognize it, and only saves the bitsequence ones?

Background: Using identical pictures in different parts, with the option to adjust later, but currently identical (e.g. btn_menu + btn_web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. All your PNGs are saved as-is in `.apk`, which is, by the way, a kind of ZIP archive - so you can use any archiver to see its contents and all of your PNGs untouched.

Comment: Damn :-) I was hopeing for more intelligence, to ignore the tradeoff of seperate images, even if identical bits... Well, then I should possible stick to the same image (its a library project, therefore I even care, used in many projects).